# View Shared Folders from Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal.app

How can one list the shared folders of a server from the OSX Terminal? For example, I know that on `server1`, there are several shared folders, but to mount them, I need to know the name of these folders before I can mount them

Comment: And are you looking for the shares on the current logged in OSX system, or on a remote OSX system?

Answer (score 17):

### SMB

Mac OS X 10.7 and above have the [`smbutil(1)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/smbutil.1.html) command, which lists SMB shares (i.e. Windows shares):

```
smbutil view //user@hostname
```

In OS X versions prior to Lion (10.7), the [`smbclient(1)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/10.6/man1/smbclient.1.html) command was shipped:

```
smbclient -L //user@hostname
```

For more options, check the respective manpages.

### NFS

For NFS, [`showmount(8)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/showmount.8.html) lists all available mounts on a host:

```
showmount hostname
```

### AFP

None I'm aware of at the moment. See this Stack Overflow question: [How to list AFP shares from command-line (MacOS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796142/how-to-list-afp-shares-from-command-line-macos)

Comment: to connect as quest: `smbutil view -g //hostname`

Answer (score 8):

For those who, like me, land here looking for a way to "View Shared Folders from Terminal" as asked in the title, but *on the local machine*, not on a remote server:

Samba has `testparm` to list the shares defined on the local machine, but current MacOS versions don't use Samba anymore. The equivalent command on MacOS is now

```
sharing -l
```

The `-l` option lists existing shares on the local machine (both afp and smb).

Answer (score 0):

For NFS shares.

showmount server1 
[OSX showmount Man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/showmount.8.html)

For SMB and AFS no idea.